# A question about Fleury's algorithm

Tags: graphs

The following is the Problem 1.4 in [1]:

**Finding an Eulerian path.** Show that if a connected graph has two vertices of odd degree and we start at one of them, Fleury's algorithm will produce an Eulerian path, and that if all vertices have even degree, it (Fleury's algorithm) will produce an Eulerian cycle no matter where we start.

Reference

[1] C. Moore and S. Mertens, *The Nature of Computation*, Oxford University Press, 2015.

---

I have tried to answer this question for a long time, but I don't have any idea. By the way, this question is not my homework, I am just interested in solving this question.

Comment: This is a rather standard topic, and is covered in many textbooks and lecture notes.

Comment: See for example Theorem 6.5 here: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/wilsongraph.pdf.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have read Theorem 6.5 and its proof in the PDF file. I think Theorem 6.5 in Wilson's book and Problem 1.4 in [1] are different because the former does not consider the degree of vertices but the latter does. Could you please answer my question directly? Thank you.

Comment: If there is more than one version of Fleury's algorithm, you'll have to spell it out. Not all of us have access to all books in the world.

Comment: In [1], the authors wrote: "Now consider the following simple rule, known as Fleury's algorithm: at each step, consider the graph $G'$ formed by the edges you have not yet crossed, and only cross a bridge of $G'$ if you have to.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the algorithm in Theorem 6.5.

Comment: Yes, the two algorithms are the same. But I think the problems are not the same.

Comment: Theorem 6.5 is about Eulerian graphs, whereas your question is also about "semi-Eulerian" graphs. I'm sure modifying the proof to handle this case won't be too difficult. There is absolutely no reason to spell it out. It will do you good to adapt the proof on your own.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you.